# ZF2 project without composer

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

I have to run a ZF2 project on a production server where I have no internet connection, so please don't answer with; "get composer" ;)
I copied the whole project from a running environment and now I have an error and I do not find the answer:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Loader\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Autoloader class Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader must implement Zend\Loader\SplAutoloader'

I have a presumption it has to do with composer but how will I solve this? Thank you for any answer... Andrea

Comment: What version of PHP do you have on the new server?

Comment: an old one:  5.3.3 :)

Comment: Then that's probably the issue. ZF 2.3 & 2.4 required PHP 5.3.23 or above. PHP 5.3 reached end of life in August 2014, you may need to find a host with a more current PHP version, if you're not in a position to update it  yourself.

Comment: I passed the message and will give feeback on this in the next few days